# Analyze the logical forms of the following statement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

$B ∈ \{\mathcal{P} (A) | A ∈ F\}$; where $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the power set of $A$ and $F$ means Family of sets

the book gave the following steps:

$$∃A ∈ F(B = \mathcal{P} (A))$$

$$∀x(x ∈ B \iff x ⊆ A)$$

$$∃A ∈ F ∀x(x ∈ B \iff ∀y(y ∈ x → y ∈ A))$$

Basically, i do not understand $B=\mathcal{P}(A)$.
The way i reasoned through this is if $B$ is an element of the set of unique subsets of the set $A$ then $B$ is a subset of $A$ where $A$ is a set element of $F$.
Now if $B$ is a subset of $A$ then every element in $B$ must be in $A$, but the converse does not necessarily hold true. Where in my line of reasoning was i mistaken? Thanks!

Comment: But $B$ **is** a set of all subsets of the set $A$, not an element of this set.

Comment: why is there a B∈{...}? don't the ∈ indicate B is an element of P(A)?

Comment: $B$ belongs to the set consisting of all the power sets of elements of $F$, and is equal to one of these power sets, namely, $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Read it aloud: $B$ is an element of the set of all the $\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that $A$ belongs to $F$.  So, $B$ is one of the $\mathcal{P}(A)$s.

Comment: dammit i was reading it wrong all along lol